# MYSQL how to calculate a percentage value with a join query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables,

```
User_packages(id,customer_id,total,vat,government_tax )

Payments(package_id,amount)
```

One User_packages (Holiday package) can have many payments. Which means the total amount can be paid installment wise.

My goal is to display User_packages id and the percentage amount that the customer paid.
and the

**full total = total + vat + government tax**

User_packages

```
id | customer_id | total | vat | government_tax
1  | 1           | 2500  |100  | 50
2  | 2           | 4500  |100  | 50
3  | 1           | 5000  |200  |100
```

Payments

```
package_id | amount
1          | 500
1          | 2000
3          | 5000
3          | 300
```

MY EXPECTED RESULTS WOULD BE

```
package_id | payment percentage
1          | 94
2          | 0
3          | 100
```

How do I achieve this using MYSQL?
All I did up to now is the join query

```
SELECT User_packages.id,Payments.amount FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
left join Payments on User_packages.id = Payments.package_id;
```

I am using **Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want:

```
SELECT u.id, COALESCE(ROUND(p.amount / (u.total + u.vat + u.government_tax) * 100), 0) AS payment_percentage
FROM user_packages u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT package_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
           FROM payments
           GROUP BY package_id) p ON p.package_id = u.id
```

Output:

```
id  payment_percentage
1   94
2   0
3   100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4d97e3cdb2f9316b0c3c3be5591cfbe)

Comment: Thanks this works. If User_packages has a column called status if I want to filter a records with belongs to one status for example 'confirmed'. Is it okay to put the where clause en to  this query? where u.status = 'confirmed'

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT User_packages.id,(coalesce(amt,0)*100.0)/(total+Vat+government_tax) as percentage
FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
left join 
(select package_id,sum(amount) as amt from Payments group by package_id) as pay
on User_packages.id = pay.package_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT User_packages.id,(Amounts.total + User_packages.vat + User_packages.government_tax) as 'payment percentage'
FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
JOIN (SELECT package_id, sum(amount) as total FROM Payments GROUP BY package_id) as Amounts
ON User_packages.id = Amounts.package_id;
```